# What does 'this' keyword Refer to in this Method

Tags: javascript

I'm just a bit confused about how the `this` keyword is used in this context. It is placed in an anonymous function with the parameter callback and is then used as such: `callback(this[i], i, this)`. The exercise doesn't go into depth, but I understand that the `this` is referring to the `ar` object that is in the __proto__. Why are 3 arguments being placed in the anonymous function's parameter `callback(this[i],i,this)`and how is it working under the hood? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Just to add to what was previously said, the exercise asked for me to implement my own version of `Array.prototype.map`.

```
Array.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  let arr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    arr.push(callback(this[i], i , this))
  }

  return arr;
}

let  ar = new Array()
```

Comment: the snippet is broken. there's an extra closing bracket `{` in the end. perhaps you missed the function's definition line?

Comment: Check the documentation about [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), in particular the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) that the callback function receives in order to understand what they are. I hope this gives you some clarification.

Comment: Best way to find out: `console.log(this);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `map` function will be called on an `Array` instance, so in the following lines of code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    arr.push(callback(this[i], i , this))
}
```

is as per the signature of the *callback* function passed to the `Array.prototype.map` method:

> **callback** Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking
>   three arguments:
>
> **currentValue** The current element being processed in the array.
>
> **index** Optional The index of the current element being processed in the
>   array.
>
> **array** Optional The array map was called upon.

So to breakdown the the three arguments in the `callback` function in your snippet:

`this[i]` translates to the first parameter of the `map` callback, which is the *currentValue*. As you understood correctly `this` is the array instance on which the `map` is called. So `this[i]` will refer to the value in the i<sup>th</sup> index of the array

`i` is the *index* or current index. This is the i<sup>th</sup> index of the iteration of the for loop being sent to the `callback`.

`this` is an reference to the *array* itself on which the `map` is invoked.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const callback = function(currentElement, index, array){
  console.log(`The current element ${currentElement}`);
  console.log(`The current index ${index}`);
  console.log(`The array instance ${array}`);
  return currentElement * 2; //multiplies each element with 2, this is the mapping operation
}
const mappedArray = arr.map(callback);
console.log(`The mapped array ${mappedArray}`);
```

Comment: Very informative. Great explanation. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please show me how I can pass an array or elements into the method to see how it is working? I'm kind of tripped up and tried ```console.log(Array.prototype.map())``` to see what's going on but still nothing

Comment: @BrianAquino  You can go through the polyfill of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) in MDN, it will show how it is working.  You can also refer the snippet in my answer, you don't pass an array in the map method but instead call the map on an array instance. You pass a callback function to the `map` which is essentially called with the 3 arguments as I shown. Then you would do *mapping* operation on the elements of the array.